# iOS 6 4inch simulator - tab bar not responding

Tags: iphone, ios6

When I run my iOS app designed for Iphone 4S and earlier on the iOS6 4inch retina simulator, I get purple bar underneath the app content with the tab bar at the bottom. The tabs do not respond. I have added the  Default-568h@2x launch image which fills up the screen but my content does not resize even though most nibs are set to AutoResize subviews. Also the keyboard does not come up from the bottom when I tap in a text view.

Is the simulator buggy? I thought apps if not modified would run with black bars in place of the extra screen size. With the simulator like this I have no idea how the app would look on an iPhone 5.

Thanks

Comment: Check the size of the window (`UIWindow`). Make sure if make the window the same size as the screen: `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`

Comment: Does your tabbar disappear when you do `[self.view setClipsToBounds:YES];` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `UIWindow` containing your `UITabBarController` has a frame size smaller than the iPhone 5 resolution supported in iOS 6.

To resolve this behavior, set the property in Interface Builder of the `UIWindow->Size` to be `Retina 4 Full Screen`

Alternatively, to handle this in your code, set the frame to the main screen bounds:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Once I did this, my `UITabBarController` began working again as designed.